# How to convert a JSON file to parquet using Apache Spark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am new to Apache Spark 1.3.1. How can I convert a JSON file to Parquet?

Comment: You could also use Apache Drill (maybe easier to setup), you could convert JSON from a local-filesystem to HDFS Parquet in 1 line of SQL: "CREATE TABLE dfs.drill.`/test5/` AS (SELECT *  FROM dfs.gen.`/2016/10/*/*.json` e);", if you are interested => https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Spark 1.4 and later**

You can use sparkSQL to read first the JSON file into an DataFrame, then writing the DataFrame as parquet file.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("path/to/json/file")
df.write.parquet("path/to/parquet/file")
```

or

```
df.save("path/to/parquet/file", "parquet")
```

Check [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets) and [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) for examples and more details.

**Spark 1.3.1**

```
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("path/to/json/file")
df.saveAsParquetFile("path/to/parquet/file")
```

**Issue related to Windows and Spark 1.3.1**

Saving a DataFrame as a parquet file on Windows will throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, as described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6961).

In that case, please consider to upgrade to a more recent Spark version.

Comment: @eddard.stark I have updated my answer to include Spark 1.3.1

Comment: getting a NullPointerException when I try to saveAsParquetFile

Comment: Are you trying this on Spark Shell or in some IDE?

Comment: I am using spark-shell

Comment: I am using spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6

Comment: I have just exactly tried these two lines of code on spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6 and it worked. Please check your code. and make sure you are not writing in a non-existing directory and you are correctly reading the file into the DataFrame.

Comment: I am working inside the bin folder. Is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100463/discussion-between-rami-and-eddard-stark).